# Chrome extension, after upgrade, might users still use old version?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to edit and then publish my Chrome extension. I know that it sometimes takes over an hour to publish an extension, but once it has been published, can I assume that all users are using this new extension version? Or might they still be using the old one for a while? And, if so, for how long?

I publish via the Chrome dashboard. Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask. I have tried searching through Chrome's documentation.

Issue: I need to update my server side code, but if a user is still using the old extension version, then it will fail very badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not make any assumptions about the extension update frequency. The update frequency is [5 hours by default](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/extensions/common/constants.cc&cl=GROK&ct=xref_jump_to_def&l=41&gsn=kDefaultUpdateFrequencySeconds). This value can be changed by the user through the `--extensions-update-frequency` flag. In practice, most users will stick to the defaults though. And do not forget that it is unreasonable to expect that all of your users have their computer online all the time.

You should keep the code for the old and new version at the server's side. If you haven't done before, include a version identifier in your request. This version identifier does not need to map 1:1 to your Chrome extension version; just use a value and keep incrementing it for every significant API update.

If you did not include a version identifier in your previous version, just assume that the user is using the old version if the version identifier is missing from the request, and consistently include the version identifier in requests from your new Chrome extension.

---

If you have set a [`minimum_chrome_version`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/minimum_chrome_version.html) in your manifest file, then the user will also be stuck at an old version of your extension if they use an older Chrome version.

---

Though not relevant for your specific situation, extension authors can choose to distribute their extension to a specific percentage of users via the dashboard at the Chrome Web store. When this feature is used, you obviously have users who are still using the old version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle in your code the possibility of users having the old version. Its not published how long that might be but from experience it can be a full day at least.

Comment: Has you personal experience really been a full day? Another answer says that Google updates it every few hours.

Answer (score 0):

According to **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html)** and **[other sources](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/KwF994PEZ-c)** the update happens within a few hours from publishing.

> Every few hours, the browser checks whether any installed extensions or apps...
>
> The default update check frequency is several hours,

I suggest you implement a mechanism to check the version of the extension making the request and if it is not current, either fallback to differently handling the request (based on the old server-side code), or inform the user they have to update (although I would not advice that, as it might scare and annoy users).

In order to force an update of one's extension:

> but you can force an update using the Extensions page's Update extensions now button.

Basically, you have to go to the Extensions page, check "Developer mode" and press the "Update extensions" button that appears.

---

**Bottom line**
I would:

1. Implement a mechanism to include the version in a request
2. Maintain two code based on the server (for a few days only)
3. serve each request based on the version

Comment: The extension button only updates my own personal copy of any extensions, no?  I have now published a new extension version that handles both the old and the new server side code. I guess I will wait a day, change my server side code, and then cross my fingers. But, yes, I should in the future include the extension version in the info that I send to the server. Doesn't help me this time, though.

Comment: The button updates the extensions installed by the user that clicks it. I was describing a way for your users to update their extensions manually. You cannot trigger an update on your users browser :)